# How to compute the fundamental group of $Sp(n,R)$ and $Sp(n,C)$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, lie-groups, fundamental-groups

$Sp(n,R)$ and $Sp(n,C)$ are real and complex symplectic groups respectively. Brian C. Hall's GTM162 says that $Sp(n,R)$ has fundamental group $\mathbb{Z}$ and $Sp(n,C)$ is simply-connected, I hope to get a proof about this.

Comment: It's the same as computing the fundamental groups of their maximal compact subgroups, which are $U(n)$ and $Sp(n)$ (the compact symplectic group) respectively. This can be done by considering their actions on the unit spheres $S^{2n-1}$ and $S^{4n-1}$ and using the long exact sequence in homotopy, which reduces to the case $n = 1$, where $U(1) \cong S^1$ has fundamental group $\mathbb{Z}$ and $Sp(1) \cong S^3$ is simply connected.

Comment: Thank you, this is a good way.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Could you please offer me a reference or give me a bit hints, about why the $Sp(2n,\mathbb{R})$ and $Sp(2n,\mathbb{C})$ can deform to $U(n)$, $U(n,\mathbb{H})$ respectively?